# set or select the text of dropdownlist to the text : select here or any other text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set/select the text baed upon the texts I choose.  e.g I have the following code that is not selecting the text but instead is adding another line to the option.

I have a dropdownlist with the following:

```
<select id="fruit">    <option value="">select here</option>    <option value="1">apple</option>    <option value="2">pineapple</option>    <option value="3">orange</option><select>

 $("#myList option:selected").text("pineapple");
 $("#myList option:selected").text("select here");
```

How can I select the option based upon the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select one of the options based on its text, you could e.g. use: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/HGLZE/.

Also you had different IDs, but that *could* be working depending on your scenario. I just changed it to be consistent with your HTML:

```
$("#fruit option").filter(function() { // filter options
    return $(this).text() === "pineapple"; // only get option with text "pineapple" back
}).attr("selected", true); // set that option selected
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fruit option:selected").text("pineapple");
```

You had the wrong ID in you jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/f3k5X/